# pugixml, select specific child according to value from other child

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I'm using pugixml with C++ which works perfectly.
However, I would like to be able to choose a specific child from a structure like this:

```
<utcTimeOffsetInfo>
    <UtcTimeOffsetDefinition>
        <utcTimeOffsetCode>1</utcTimeOffsetCode>
        <utcTimeOffset>+0100</utcTimeOffset>
    </UtcTimeOffsetDefinition>
    <UtcTimeOffsetDefinition> 
        <utcTimeOffsetCode>2</utcTimeOffsetCode>
        <utcTimeOffset>+0200</utcTimeOffset>
    </UtcTimeOffsetDefinition>
    <UtcTimeOffsetDefinition>
        <utcTimeOffsetCode>3</utcTimeOffsetCode>
        ...
```

If I want to get the value +0200, it would be nice to be able to do something like:

```
...child("utcTimeOffsetInfo").child("UtcTimeOffsetDefinition").child_value[utcTimeOffsetCode=2]("utcTimeOffset")
```

I've looked at find_child_by_attribute, but it does not seem to fit the purpose.

Comment: This kind of behavior is more easily achievable with using xpath. I'm not sure what the exact expression will be, but it should be possible.

Comment: Do you have an XPath example on how to get the value from utcTimeOffset from a defined utcTimeOffsetCode value?

Comment: I've tried child("xml").select_single_node("/utcTimeOffsetInfo/UtcTimeOffsetDefinition/utcTimeOffsetCode=3").parent().child_value("utcTimeOffset"). But I get the error "Expression does not evaluate to node set". Could you help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use XPath for that.

```
doc.select_node("utcTimeOffsetInfo/UtcTimeOffsetDefinition[utcTimeOffsetCode=2]/utcTimeOffset")
```

(note: select_node is a short-hand for select_single_node that is available since pugixml 1.5)